# Does the True Polymorph spell form a creature with equipment?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, equipment, polymorph

When a spellcaster transforms an object or creature into a creature using the True Polymorph spell, does that creature form with equipment?

Example: if a spellcaster used *True Polymorph* to transform a twelfth level fighter into an Erinyes, would the Erinyes form with the plate armor, magical longsword, or rope of entanglement listed in its statistics block?

This isn't clear to me from *True Polymorph*'s text, which notes the "target's game statistics, including mental ability scores, are replaced by the statistics of the new form", but this doesn't address equipment.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You get all of the creature's game statistics. This includes their *default* equipment, powers, etc (otherwise your game statistics would not be the same).

However, I think something like the alternate option such as the Rope of Entanglement would be very much at the DM's discretion. There's no clear RAW here, so it's definitely up to discretion.

Comment: While I don't disagree with this answer, it could use a little more support/reasoning in terms of what spells do, and what constitutes a stat block.

Comment: I would say: Creature to Creature, No, it keeps what equipment it has; Creature to Object: Yes, it keeps  its equipment in object form; Object to Creature : Depends - if you creature to objected a creature then it gets its equipment back otherwise you get nonmagical equipment

Answer (score 23):

### A True Polymorphed creature forms without equipment

Though not official, [this tweet from Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/739901527880433664) indicates that you do not receive the equipment of a creature:

> True polymorph: if you turn into a creature, you don't also get gear from the transformation.

(He clarifies in a [followup tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/741452744108605440) that the same also applies to other transformation spells.)

The interpretation of "A spell does (only) what the description says" is consistent with how spell effects are interpreted elsewhere, and equipment is not mentioned in the spell.

This interpretation also prevents the duplication of magic items (such as a [Drow Matron Mother](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/drow-matron-mother)'s Tentacle Rod) or artifacts that should otherwise be unique. This is pertinent considering that True Polymorphing a creature into an object carries the requirement that the object be nonmagical.

### True Polymorph transforms the target into a creature

The [True Polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph) spell uses the text:

> **Creature into Creature.** If you turn a creature into another kind of creature, the new form can be any kind you choose...

The effect specifies that you choose a creature to turn into. Equipment is distinctly classified as Objects whether worn or carried by a creature. Even sentient weapons are considered objects.

As there is a separate spell effect for turning creatures into objects, the logical conclusion is that the Creature into Creature effect would not include this. The usage of the word "statistics" in this case in intended to indicate attributes, abilities, etc.

Comment: My intuition was that a creature would form with equipment, however I was unable to find anything in support of this. Though I do not generally cite Crawford as a source, I can find no reason to disagree with his interpretation in this case

Comment: An example of your last paragraph about duplicating magic items; _true polymorph_ someone into a Githyanki Knight, and now you have a +3 Silver Greatsword.

Comment: @NathanS I would include that example in the answer, however the sword "takes on the properties of a +3 greatsword in the hands of its creator" which seems aimed at preventing PCs from obtaining it.

Comment: Ah, nevermind then. But I'm sure there are other examples out there of creatures that have magic items included in their stat blocks, that was just the first one that occurred to me that I knew for certain.

Comment: As the spell specifies that you only choose a "kind" of creature, which is distinct from a specific creature (as in the *locate object* spell), yes. I believe the language is consistent with the *polymorph* spell which allows only for beasts, which do not include equipment.

Comment: Risk of item duplication alone seems a weak reason to take away equipment that is a vital part of a creature. A concerned DM can simply have the magic sword transform back into the PCs mundane rapier or whatever.

Comment: The distinction between creatures and objects is the reason; negating item duplication is simply a benefit to consistency. Though reverting the item afterward does offer a solution, it seems to conflict with the description stating, "The creature can't activate, use, wield, or otherwise benefit from any of its equipment." Keep in mind that True Polymorph is potentially permanent. As long as the effect is discussed beforehand, a player can choose a creature where the equipment is not vital or remove their gear before the transformation to benefit from their own equipment (if able to wield it).

Answer (score 10):

### When you *true polymorph* into a monster you gain its usual equipment

Note that the [*true polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph) spell's description states:

> The target's game statistics, including mental ability scores, are replaced by **the statistics of the new form**...

The question then becomes: "What count as creature's statistics?". Luckily, there is already an answer to that question [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/138783) which has 20 upvotes, no downvotes, and is accepted, leading me to believe it is generally agreed upon. The answer uses the following quote from the Monster Manual (page 6):

> A monster's statistics, sometimes referred to as its stat block, provide the essential information that you need to run the monster...

This allows one to define the following: If it is on its statblock, it is part of the monster's statistics.
The Monster Manual goes on with short sections on each part of a creature's statistics (pages 6-11):

> 1. Size
> 2. Type
> 3. Tags
> 4. Alignment
> 5. Armor Class
> 6. Hit Points
> 7. Speed
> 8. Ability Scores
> 9. Saving Throws
> 10. Skills
> 11. Vulnerabilities, Resistances, and Immunities
> 12. Senses
> 13. Languages
> 14. Challenge
> 15. Special Traits
> 16. Actions
> 17. Reactions
> 18. Limited Usage
> 19. **Equipment**

A monster's equipment is included on its statblock and thus is included in its statistics. This is further supported by the [*simulacrum*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/simulacrum) spell which states:

> It appears to be the same as the original, but it has half the creature's hit point maximum and is formed without any equipment. **Otherwise, the illusion uses all the statistics of the creature it duplicates**, except that it is a construct.

There would be no reason to say that equipment are not created if equipment were not part of a creature's statistics. Thus, equipment are part of a creature's statistics.

***true polymorphing* into a monster will give you their usual equipment**

Answer (score 3):

### Mundane Equipment

*tldr: I allow the spell to create non-magical equipment in my own games (as that seems to follow precedent and eliminates some problems), but many creatures generate magical effects using mundane weapons*

[True Polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph) seems powerful enough to generate equipment, as creating objects is one of its options. Also (as mentioned above): creating an unequipped creature would play havoc with its stats, which is not fun and would slow down the game. Such alteration of stats does not seem to be intended by the authors, as indicated by the phrases "*The target's game statistics, including mental ability scores, are replaced by the statistics of the new form*" and "*The GM has the creature's statistics*"

However, [True Polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph) is apparently not powerful enough to create **magical** objects, as indicated by its description "*You transform the creature into a different creature, the creature into a **nonmagical** object, or the object into a creature*". Plus: generating *magical* equipment could create havoc with the game. My players seem very understanding of such a restriction... especially since they are seldom allowed to loot those same 'magical' items from fallen foes, similar to:

- [Are Erinyes' Hellish Weapons poisonous in a PC's hands?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84405/are-erinyes-hellish-weapons-poisonous-in-a-pcs-hands)
- [If you kill a Solar Angel can you use its Slaying Longbow?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/150644/if-you-kill-a-solar-angel-can-you-use-its-slaying-longbow/150655#150655)
- [What happens with the Drow's poisoned weapons when picked up by a PC?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/74576/what-happens-with-the-drows-poisoned-weapons-when-picked-up-by-a-pc)
- [Do PCs get the attack and to hit bonus from enemy weapons they may pick up?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/100607/do-pcs-get-the-attack-and-to-hit-bonus-from-enemy-weapons-they-may-pick-up)

In play this means either the creature generates magical effects using mundane weapons, or some attack effects may not occur (depending on my own judgement as DM). Since it's a 9th level spell, this seldom comes up (and at that level, the creature's gear is seldom a balance issue)