# Can you obtain a Transmuter's Stone if you "morph" into a Transmuter statblock?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, monsters, polymorph

*Volo's Guide to Monsters* contains the stat bloc for an NPC called Transmuter, who is a humanoid, CR 5, with the following trait:

> **Transmuter's Stone.** The transmuter carries a magic stone it crafted that grants its bearer one of the following effects {formatted for ease of reading}:
>
> 1. Darkvision out of a range of 60 feet
> 2. An extra 10 feet of speed while the bearer is unencumbered
> 3. Proficiency with Constitution saving throws
> 4. Resistance to acid, cold, fire, lightning or thunder damage (transmuter's choice whenever the transmuter chooses this benefit)
>      If the transmuter has the stone and casts a transmutation spell of 1st level or higher, it can change the effect of the stone.

It is, I believe, possible for a high level caster to "morph" into a Transmuter statblock, either by True Polymorping into it directly, True Polymorphing into a creature that can then Change Shape into it (such as an Ancient Metallic Dragon), or by Shapechanging into it.

My question is: if you "morph" into an NPC Transmuter, do you gain access to its Transmuter's Stone?

Comment: Related: [Does true polymorph form a creature with equipment?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/57124/33707)

Comment: A Transmuter is a subclass of Wizard, isn't it?

Comment: @Verdan Yes ("Transmutation Wizard"), but also a monster statblock ("Transmuter").

Comment: @GaelL is there any reason you think that this Q is any different from the general case outlined in the related link above? If so, you should make that aspect clearer because, to me, this reads a lot like a duplicate currently. Is it the difference between "equipment" and this ambiguous trait that might be equipment?