Can Polymorph allow access to extra spells? Or can it generally grant spells?
Could you switch out your current spells with other spells?
Or can something with no ability of magic be polymorphed into a creature capable of using magic?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to the stack Jack, take the [tour] when you have a moment. It isn’t clear what game you’re talking about, would you please clarify what that is? Also, the first question, “could you switch out your current spells with other spells”, is unclear, please clarify what you mean by this.

to temporarily replace YOUR own spells, with spells you don't have

I assumed that you are referring to the Polymorph spell: is it true? Or do you mean any other means of polymorphing?

i was initially referencing polymorph, but realized the original had some more limitations  i overlooked. alternatives are welcome.

Not with polymorph, no
The polymorph spell lets you transform into "any beast", and very few beasts have spellcasting.  A generous DM might allow you to polymorph into Traxigor (an NPC wizard who has used wish to become a beast), but even that wouldn't help, because:

The creature is limited in the actions it can perform by the nature of its new form, and it can’t speak, cast spells, or take any other action that requires hands or speech.

True polymorph allows this
The 9th-level true polymorph spell is not limited by creature type, and it has slightly different text:

The creature is limited in the actions it can perform by the nature of its new form, and it can’t speak, cast spells, or take any other action that requires hands or speech, unless its new form is capable of such actions.

so you could true polymorph someone into a creature with spellcasting and get them to spellcast for you.  (Or you could true polymorph yourself, of course, if the spellcasting you needed from the creature didn't require concentration.)

You cannot normally access to any spell under the effect of the Polymorph spell.
The spell description says (emphasis mine):

The new form can be any beast whose challenge rating is equal to or less than the target's (or the target's level, if it doesn't have a challenge rating). The target's game statistics, including mental ability scores, are replaced by the statistics of the chosen beast. It retains its alignment and personality.

To the best of my knowledge, there are no beasts with the spellcasting trait: indeed, the beast type is the game mechanic that models animals from the real world, and it extends this notion to fantastic animals, and some of them may have some magical ability.
Well, actually....
There is a tiny beast that has the spellcasting trait: Traxigor.
This monster is one of a kind, and it is not clear how this mage managed to become an otter with such powerful abilities.

And it should be noted that you cannot turn into traxigor using polymorph.

@ThomasMarkov I'd be interested to see a clear ruling on that.  https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/208497/what-statistics-are-exactly-eligible-for-polymorph/208498#208498 seems to imply that it is legal, although it notes that it "feels wrong".
